# Cauchy problem - number of solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How many solutions does this Cauchy problem have ?

$$\begin{array}{l} x^6 + y^4 = y'\\
y(2)=-1 \end{array}$$

How do I find the number of solutions ? There is another example, where the solutions are more than one:
$$\begin{array}{l}y'=3y^{2/3} \\
y(0)=0 \end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

The second one is simple since the equation is separable if you write it as $$x'=\frac{1}{3} y^{-\frac{2}{3}}$$ so $$x+c=\sqrt[3]{y}$$ and then $$y=(x+c)^3$$ If you insert the condition, then .....

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: There is also the solution $y(x)=0$, and it can 'turn on' to the cubic solution at any time.

Comment: @Michael. You are totally correct, indeed. I always miss this kind of solution. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, note that $f(x,y)=x^6+y^4$ is continuous in $x$ and locally Lipschitz continuous in $y$. You can see the latter by differentiating with respect to $y$ and noting that the result is bounded over a bounded set. Then apply Picard-Lindelöf.